# 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' When Index is set to 0 through List.count?

Tags: c#

Why is there IndexOutOfRange exception being thrown? The index is set to iterate through 0 to the List.Count... I'll post my code below.

```
public void ShowButtons()
{
    Appliances = data.GetAppliances();

    for (int x = 0; x <= Appliances.Count; x++)
    {
        appButtons[x] = new Button();
        appButtons[x].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
        appButtons[x].Text = Appliances[x].Name;
        ButtonBoard.Controls.Add(appButtons[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is `x <= Appliances.Count`. Since it is indexed from zero, you need to use `x < Appliances.Count`; no equality. This is out of range. And the Out of range exception can also be caused by `appButtons[x]`. How many buttons do you have in the `appButtons` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop should go upto `Appliances.Count-1` or it can be like @Julo said

> The problem is x <= Appliances.Count. Since it is indexed from zero,
>   you need to use x < Appliances.Count; no equality. This is out of
>   range.

Your code should be

```
for (int x = 0; x < Appliances.Count; x++)
            {
                appButtons[x] = new Button();
                appButtons[x].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
                appButtons[x].Text = Appliances[x].Name;
                ButtonBoard.Controls.Add(appButtons[x]);
            }
```

or it can be

```
for (int x = 0; x <= Appliances.Count-1; x++)
            {
                appButtons[x] = new Button();
                appButtons[x].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
                appButtons[x].Text = Appliances[x].Name;
                ButtonBoard.Controls.Add(appButtons[x]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Count returns number of elements in an array.
If your array is of length 5, i.e

```
int[] array = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

**Array index starts from 0 to n, in your case 0 to 4.**

When you iterate array you need to iterate from 0 to n - 1 as *indexing starts from 0*. Instead of doing for loop upto `Application.Count`, iterate upto **`Application.Count - 1`**

```
for (int x = 0; x <= Appliances.Count-1; x++)
            {
                appButtons[x] = new Button();
                appButtons[x].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
                appButtons[x].Text = Appliances[x].Name;
                ButtonBoard.Controls.Add(appButtons[x]);
            }
```